# Why total ignores filter?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a row with calculated field - TOTAL([num_launches]), where num_launches is also calculated field = SUM([count])

When I filter launches by date of the launch(which is not in the rows), leaving only 5 of 10 launches e.g., total doesn't change. However, when I filter by the name of launches it works... Is that the common problem and maybe someone knows how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to select your field on the filter shelf and “add it to the context”. Context filters will be applied early.

To better understand the timing of filters, calculations and how to obtain the results you wish, learn about Tableau’s “order of operations”. There is a brief discussion in the on-line help, and more in depth info in the training and conference videos.